# Quartz.Net CronExpression Builder

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have some GUI controls forming a typical windows scheduler (Date\Time pickers, check boxes, etc) that I would like to build a CronExpression string from.

Does anyone know of a good way to build the expression string, either a pre-existing class or good approaches to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cron expressions in Quartz.Net are made up of 7 [sub-expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html):

```
1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day-of-Month
5. Month
6. Day-of-Week
7. Year (optional field)
```

I usually use [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to create my own cron expressions.

Another option is this other [tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) which works pretty well.

Comment: What I'd like to do is have a class where I can set the schedule details via properties and have it create an appropriate Cron expression.

Comment: I've tried to find something like that a couple of months ago but I haven't been successful so I ended up build mine own one, very simple though, cause I had to deal with very few situations. If you read this tutorial http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html it shouldn't be to difficiult to build even a complex one.

Answer (score 6):

I used this jQuery plug-in with asp.net and Quartz.Net to schedule the cron jobs: http://shawnchin.github.com/jquery-cron/

This was a good alternative too: http://www.geekytidbits.com/cron-expression-descriptor-demo/Default.aspx

Comment: I don't think shawnchin works with quartz, it needs to be modified

Comment: @JerryLiang It doesn't work. Quartz.net uses 6 parts cron expressions, with a 7th optional one, but this jquery plugin creates expressions with only 5 parts, so it's not compatible with Quartz.

Answer (score 2):

His question is whether there is a way to build a cron expression using an interface (may be a window made through JavaScript) where there are check boxes and radio buttons to check and select options. And according to selected and checked option a cron expression will be created.

Answer to this question is you have to write logic after checking all the options that has been checked. There is no direct way to do this.